# nunjucks is not a function

Tags: vite, nunjucks

I have created a project using vite and added tailwind css on this project. Now I want to add nunjucks for templating. i have used [nunjucks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-nunjucks) plugin on vite.congig.js file. here is this.

```js
import nunjucks from "vite-plugin-nunjucks";

export default {
    plugins: [nunjucks({})],
    root: "src",
    build: {
        outDir: "../dist",
        emptyOutDir: true,
    },
};
```

when i nun `npm run dev` the following error shows.

```bash
failed to load config from project_path/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: nunjucks is not a function
    at project_path/vite.config.js.timestamp-1681991273043-853f53f95fa9d.mjs:4:13
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

what might me the reason ?

I applied all procedures based on documentation but didn't get the result. After running `npm run dev` the project should run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugins this way `plugins: [nunjucks.default()],`

Here is the full code :

```js
import nunjucks from "vite-plugin-nunjucks";

export default {
    plugins: [nunjucks.default()],
    root: "src",
    build: {
        outDir: "../dist",
        emptyOutDir: true,
    },
};
```

The answer is based on the issue created on this plugin's GitHub repository.
[read the issue.](https://github.com/Jax-p/vite-plugin-nunjucks/issues/12)